# Permanent Solution for "chrome.exe" "--allow-file-access-from-files"

Tags: java, powershell, google-chrome

Everytime I have to open some Java or flash based application on chrome (edge works fine) , I ll have to enter `"chrome.exe" "--allow-file-access-from-files"` command on powershell. 
Its frustrating when I am in middle of something like 8-tabs opened in chrome then
 I ll have to close the chrome from task manager and enter the command in powershell in order to run some flash based website I am creating. 
Is there a permanent solution for this?
I have already installed latest verson of flash and java . Microsoft framenet is also of latest.

Comment: I know this is not part of the question but just a friendly reminder that Flash End of Life is 2020. It might be best to reskill the websites with more modern standards.
[link](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-flash-update/)

Comment: Short of creating a shortcut with the flag included and always running chrome with the flag, you could try: [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)